# Android app name under settings

Tags: android, settings

How can I change the name of my app on the Android device settings?  In other words, if the user hits settings, then Apps, there is a list of apps.  I want to change its name there.

This is what I have currently in my manifest.  And the name on that screen is "com.jockusch.freedroidcalculator".  Ugh.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.jockusch.freedroidcalculator" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:label="Free Graphing Calculator">
  <uses-sdk android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <application android:theme="@style/Theme.Foo" android:icon="@drawable/CalculatorAppIcon">
    <activity android:name="jockusch.calculator.droid.MainTabActivity" android:label="Free Graphing Calculator">
      <intent-filter android:label="Free GraCalc">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Try adding `android:label="@string/app_name"` inside `<application>`?

Comment: You cannot achieve this, since the system is deciding to show only list of applications name in its setting.

Comment: You are using it twice. `<intent-filter android:label="Free GraCalc">` & <activity android:name="jockusch.calculator.droid.MainTabActivity" `android:label="Free Graphing Calculator"`>

Comment: remove "android:label" from manifest tag and add to application tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

inside your strings.xml

```
<string name="app_name">your app name</string>
```